# How to get data from Google Sheet action?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

How i can get data from the actions applied to a google sheet?
for example: Cell A1 edited and its value changed from null to another string or number and i want to get that value.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you want to get that data? with a script? in another cell?

Comment: @LioraHaydont i want to store data that people edited real-time.

Comment: @MinhTuan store where, store how? You question is too broad to be answered at the moment